# Java Rest API client - GET method - Error 415

Tags: java, apache, rest, cxf, cxf-client

I am new to writing Java client for Restful API using Apache CXF.

On running below code I am getting error 415 returned which when I looked online shows as "unsupported media type". In order to fix it I changed the code to "target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)" from original target.request(). However this didn't fix the code.

What is the best way to debug this issue?
Thanks a lot in advance for your time.

**Update:** After discussion with the Rest API developer I came to know that I need to add a header "("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");". but I am not sure how to add a header. Does anyone know how to add this header here?

```
package com.blackhawk.ivr.restAPI.client;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class BlissRestAPI {

public static final String BLISS_SERVICRE_URL = "http://x.x.x.x:9090/services";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();      
    WebTarget target = client.target(BLISS_SERVICRE_URL);
    target = target.path("/cardmanagementservices/v3/card/status").queryParam("ani", "xxxxxxxxxx").queryParam("card.expiration", "xxxxxx").queryParam("card.number", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").queryParam("channel.id", "xyz");
    Invocation.Builder builder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);             
    Response response = builder.get();
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());       
    response.close();
    client.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Does it execute succesfully if you try: MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN?

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried but it did not work      ->             target.request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

Answer (score 0):

First you can change the media type as given below.

- Client: MediaType.APPLICATION_XML
- Rest: MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

JAX-WS are Java standard to build web service. So you have used it here, As my knowledge it is easy to use axis 2 to this kind of web services and clients since there are more implementations of JAX-WS. So i will give you a solution using apache axis technology.

```
import org.apache.axis.client.Call;
import org.apache.axis.client.Service;
import org.apache.axis.encoding.XMLType;

import javax.xml.rpc.ParameterMode;


public class axisClient {

   public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {

      String endpoint = "http://localhost:8090/archive_name/service_name.jws";

      Service service = new Service();
      Call call    = (Call) service.createCall();



      call.setTargetEndpointAddress( new java.net.URL(endpoint) );
      call.setOperationName( "service_method_name" );
      call.addParameter("parameter_name", XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN );
      call.setReturnType( XMLType.XSD_STRING );
      call.setProperty(Call.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

      String jsonString = (String) call.invoke( new Object [] { "parameter_value"});

      System.out.println("Got result : " + jsonString);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using below code (got 200 status returned)

```
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(BLISS_SERVICRE_URL);
    client.path("/cardmanagementservices/v3/card/status").query("ani", "xxxxxxxxxx").query("card.expiration", "xxxxxx").query("card.number", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx").query("channel.id", "xxxxx");
    client.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    client.header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    Response response = client.get();
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
```